# Magento 2 Load UI grid only after filter search

Tags: magento2, ui-grid

I have created custom module. In that I am displaying product collection in Ui grid. I have extend `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider` to display collections.

What is my requirement :
I want to display(load) collection only after user search anything from filter.

The UI grid should not display any product until user search anything from filter.

**My code For this file**
`app/code/Company/module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Vendor/ProductDataProvider.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Vendor;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class ProductDataProvider
 */
class ProductDataProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider
{

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface[] $addFieldStrategies
     * @param \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface[] $addFilterStrategies
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $addFieldStrategies = [],
        array $addFilterStrategies = [],
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $collectionFactory, $addFieldStrategies, $addFilterStrategies, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');
        $this->collection->addAttributeToFilter('has_options', '1');
        $this->collection->joinField(
            'qty',
            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your extended `ProductDataProvider` code.

Comment: @ChiragPatel I have updated my answer